# How to make Windows completely "forget" a system-tray icon?

Tags: windows, taskbar, icons

Ok, so you know how you can right-click the taskbar in Windows, then click Taskbar settings, and under the Notification area toward the bottom, click "Select which icons appear on the taskbar" as shown in the screenshot below, then toggle certain software icons On and Off?

[image: Screenshot of the location of the "Select which icons appear on the taskbar" option.]

My question is: **How does one make Windows completely "forget" one of those icons?**

So that if I try to select which icons appear on the taskbar in the future, I simply never see some of these icons after removing them. And I understand that running the software pertaining to some of those icons again will most probably simply re-add the icons to that list.

My guess is that this requires editing the registry, but where exactly?

Thank you for any help with this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use this .bat file from this site.
https://www.tenforums.com/tutorials/5662-reset-notification-area-icons-windows-10-a.html

Comment: Thank you. It's not ideal to reset the whole notification area and have to redo all the other options but that does achieve the goal of making Windows forget one or two of the icons, albeit in an "overkill" fashion. I'll pick this as the answer, at least until there's an option to pick specific icons and remove them from history.